# Read from Github in R

Tags: r, github

I am trying to run this code in R:

```
url = "https://github.com/Robinlovelace/sdvwR/raw/master/data/gps-trace.gpx"
download.file(url, destfile = "shef2leeds.gpx", method = "wget")

library(rgdal)
shef2leeds <- readOGR("shef2leeds.gpx", layer = "tracks")
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open data source
```

Comment: what's the result of `file.exists("shef2leeds.gpx")`? you may not have permission to write the file. works like a charm on my machine.

Comment: You code does not run on my machine, only when removing `method = "wget"` it works fine.

Comment: What's your R version and OS?